# Display negative values in the first quarter of a bar chart but with different bar color than the positive values

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I create a bar plot using ggplot in combination with plotly and I would like to know if there is a way to display the negative values above the x-axis as positive but with a different color (red) than the blue and also a legend that would clarify that blue are the positive values and red the negatives. Something like:

[image]

```
date<-c(as.Date("2020-09-15", "%Y-%m-%d"),as.Date("2020-09-14", "%Y-%m-%d"),
        as.Date("2020-09-13", "%Y-%m-%d"),as.Date("2020-09-12", "%Y-%m-%d"),
        as.Date("2020-09-15", "%Y-%m-%d"),as.Date("2020-09-14", "%Y-%m-%d"),
        as.Date("2020-09-13", "%Y-%m-%d"),as.Date("2020-09-12", "%Y-%m-%d"))
value<-c(5,6,7,8,-3,-5,6,8)
df<-data.frame(date,value)

# Minimal theme + blue fill color
p<-ggplot(data=df, aes(x=date, y=value)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", fill="steelblue")+
  theme_minimal()+ labs(x = "Date of Specimen Collection",y="Total Tests per Day")
ggplotly(p)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something along these lines?

```
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(pos_neg = if_else(value > 0, "Positive", "Negative"))
# Minimal theme + blue fill color
p<-ggplot(data=df, aes(x=date, y=abs(value), fill = pos_neg)) +
  geom_bar(position = "dodge", stat="identity")+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("red","steelblue")) +
  theme_minimal()+ labs(x = "Date of Specimen Collection",y="Total Tests per Day")
ggplotly(p)
```

Another Option:

```
p1 <- ggplot(data=df) +
  geom_bar(data = filter(df, pos_neg == "Positive"), aes(x=date, y=abs(value)), position = "stack", stat="identity", fill = "steelblue")+
  geom_bar(data = filter(df, pos_neg == "Negative"), aes(x=date, y=abs(value)), position = "stack", stat="identity", fill = "red")
ggplotly(p1)
```

UPDATE TO OPTION 2:
To get the legend labels and colours `fill` has to be in the `aes`.

```
colours <- c("Positive" = "steelblue", "Negative" = "red")

p1 <- ggplot(data=df) +
  geom_bar(data = filter(df, pos_neg == "Positive"), aes(x=date, y=abs(value), fill = pos_neg), position = "stack", stat="identity")+
  geom_bar(data = filter(df, pos_neg == "Negative"), aes(x=date, y=abs(value), fill = pos_neg), position = "stack", stat="identity")+
  scale_fill_manual(values = colours, name = "Positive/Negative") +
  # scale_fill_manual(values = c("Positive" = "steelblue", "Negative" = "red"), name = "Positive/Negative") + #another way to achieve colours
  labs(x = "Date of Specimen Collection",y="Total Tests per Day") +
  theme_minimal()

ggplotly(p1)
```

I can tidy this up with an update if it is looking correct

Comment: regarding the color yes but the bars should be over 0, not below, like the positive ones.

Comment: @firmo Ok I think I see what you want and updated my answer but I'm struggling to make it work exactly how I understand you want it to. I wrapped the data in `abs` and used `position = "dodge"` which makes them show side-by-side. `position = "stack"` gave me cumulative bars which I don't think you want?. Sometimes ggplot makes it very difficult to do things if they are considered "bad practice" (especially multi axis stuff!) but I'm not sure if that is the case here. I might just be missing something! If this is still not right I'll remove my answer :)

Comment: I think I got it! see update. Don't know why I didn't think of this before XD